# A little help for a correct date + hour:minute like Oracle for Postgresql

Tags: oracle, postgresql

On my db on Oracle i select this query

```
17-DIC-20 18:33:24  |Title1                  |1980        |Thriller        |1:30      |Divx      |Eng
```

The same thing I did on Postgres

```
 3765 | Title1 | 1992 | Thriller | 1:30   | Divx | Eng | 2020-12-17 18:20:07.784068 | 2020-12-17 18:20:07.784068
```

I really dislike the column format 18:20:07.784068 and I prefer something like

```
2020-12-17 18:20:07
```

So I recreate the view modifing the column

```
video=# drop view gener2;
DROP VIEW


video=# create view gener2 as SELECT title.idtitle,
    title.title,
    title.year,
    genre.genre,
    lenght.lenght,
    type.type,
    lang.lang,
cast (title.time as date) FROM title,
    genre,
    lenght,
    type,
    lang
  WHERE title.genre = genre.idgenre AND title.lenght = durata.iddurata AND title.type = type.idtype AND title.lang = lang.idlang                                                                                                                        ORDER BY title.idtitle;
CREATE VIEW

video=# select * from gener2  offset 3031 limit 1 ;
3765 | Title1 | 1992 | Thriller | 1:30   | Divx | Eng | 2020-12-17
```

My simple question is..how to obtain a correct format like those examples?

```
2020-12-17 18:30
2020-12-17 16:33
2020-12-17 14:55
```

I have created the Oracle column with this value

```
TIMESTAMP(0) DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This is one way: select to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')

Comment: add as answer please so I can close the question

Comment: 1) Create the Postgres column the same way `TIMESTAMP(0) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL`  2) Cast the existing field to eliminate fractional seconds: `select timestamp_fld::timestamp(0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way: `select to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')`

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate oracle column `TIMESTAMP(0) DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL;` as `timestamp(0) not null default now()`.

You should also check for your [Locale and Formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-FORMAT) settings.
You can [set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) configuration `LC_TIME` to `"en_US"` either in PostgreSQL configuration (for all users as default) or your session (or maybe just the transaction)

Here is a sample;

```
--test format without data
set LC_TIME to "en_US";  -- or "C" which is same in this case
select now()::timestamp(0);

-- test format with data
create table foo (
 id serial,
 bar timestamp(0) not null default now()
);
insert into foo DEFAULT VALUES;
select * from foo;

/*
Sample result
---------------------
 2020-12-17 21:53:57
(1 row)
*/
```